# How do I completely disable caching in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

So I opened the cache floodgates in my Cakephp app and now I want to close them...

I've done pretty much everything I can: delete all files in the tmp folder (but not the folders), turned 'Cache.disable' on in the core.php file in my app, have tried clearing the cache from within some controllers with clearCache() and Cache::clear() (but I suspect this doesn't work because it's not loading the controller -- due to caching).

I've pretty much effectively halted my development process just because caching won't turn off.  Anyone have some ideas that I could try?  I'm starting to think it may be within the browser or maybe my hosting service, but it's probably just Cakephp messing with me.

Comment: Well have you tried clearing your browser cache? Also how are you assessing if it's caching your application? Do bear in mind that even with caching off, /tmp/cache will still have files in there, as models are always cached.

Comment: The way I've tried to assess if it's caching is by inserting a hi into a view and seeing if it comes up after a reload and, yes, an emptying of the browser cache.

As a side note, I have figured out the problem, but now I have no idea how to deal with it: the view cache file keeps resurfacing after every manual delete I make...  even though I have every cache feature I can find disabled.  why is it still caching the view in spite of this?

Comment: Perhaps try it with debug:0 set in the config, as I know that debug:2 will regenerate everything on every request. Otherwise perhaps the file is read only, or your ftp client ins't reporting the folder properly? Just a thought :)

Answer (score 13):

To rule out browser caching as the root cause, you might try adding the following lines:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate');                  // HTTP/1.1
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);    // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');                                       // Date in the past  
header('Expires: 0', false); 
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

The combination of all these cache-busting HTTP headers has, in my experience, worked in all browsers, and has got around some very aggressive caching proxies as well.

Comment: Where exactly can I add these lines of code?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You could look your controller code for some element caching and set them to false. This applies to app_controller.php or Controller/AppController.php depending on version of Cake you use.

```
Controller::cacheAction = false

echo $this->element('latest_comments', array(), array('cache' => false));
```

You could try adding `Controller::disableCache();` in your controller action.

Comment: I think it should be `echo $this->element('latest_comments',array(), array('cache' => false));`

Comment: public $cacheAction = false; for your AppController in CakePHP 2

Answer (score 3):

Kind of a long shot (plus this thread is old, but oh well), but I had a similar problem: I couldn't get IE to quit caching ajax requests (using jQuery). After much heartache and headache a simple:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

did the trick. Gotta love IE...

Comment: If anything, that's a good thing for IE to do that. And this is jQuery, not Cake.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem once with the model getting cached and no longer reflected the schema of the table.

I had to update my /config/core.php and set "debug:2" 
This disables the caching of my models and fixed my problems.

Comment: This does the task, but also has the unintended effect of showing detailed errors, SQL statements etc on the page. Debug mode 2 is good for development, Debug mode 0 is good for production (public view). For the current task see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5901246 , and for an explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3118292/216084 .

Answer (score 0):

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#globally-enable-or-disable-cache

> static Cake\Cache\Cache::disable¶
>   You may need to disable all Cache read & writes when trying to figure out cache expiration related issues. You can do this using enable() and disable():